# How to set the [NSString defaultCStringEncoding]?

Tags: macos, nsstring, osx-lion

How do I change the value of the `[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]` return value? What kind of environment variables or system settings do I need to change?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to change this? What's your actual goal here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can change it, and from the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/defaultCStringEncoding):

> in general this encoding should be used rarely, if at all.

Use this method instead:

```
+ (id)stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
```

Comment: I don't want to change it at runtime. I want to configure my system to return a different one.

Comment: @angerman This is the only clue in the reference about how it's determined: "This method returns a user-dependent encoding who value is derived from user's default language and potentially other factors".

Comment: You can set it to some strange value by choosing Chinese or Japanese System language. But I fail to see how to set it to NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: While it's not documented, the value is basically "what classic Mac OS would use for this system", which is `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` for most Western European settings. There's no way to change that without a lot of deep hackery. Any such hackery will probably break any obsolete programs that depend on `defaultCStringEncoding`, and be irrelevant to any modern programs.

Comment: Which is exactly why I want to know who changes the value and brakes programs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution. You can use `~/.CFUserTextEncoding` to mess with the systems `defaultCStringEncoding` if you really want. (Like Adobe did...)

For more see: https://superuser.com/questions/82123/mac-whats-cfusertextencoding-for

interestingly it *does* change the behavior of `[NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding:]` though. Similarly you can force the `defaultCStringEncoding` to be `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` by setting the file above to `0:0`.